# Getting the column names of a Data Frame with sapply

Tags: r

I want to get the columns names of a Data Frame with the following code:

```
DF <- data.frame(X=c(1,2), Y=c(3,4))
as.character(sapply(DF, names))
```

I've got the following:

```
"NULL" "NULL"
```

but I need the following result:

```
"X" "Y"
```

How can I do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

But there's a function to do it directly. See `?colnames`

```
colnames(DF)
[1] "X" "Y"
```

In this case you could also do

```
names(DF)
[1] "X" "Y"
```

either way you don't need `sapply` to extract the column names.

If you name the rows `names` still only gives the column names:

```
rownames(DF)<-list("a","b")
DF
  X Y
a 1 3
b 2 4
names(DF)
[1] "X" "Y"
```

but the `rownames` function gets the row names for you:

```
rownames(DF)
[1] "a" "b"
```

If you had a list of data frames with the same number of columns you might perhaps use `sapply` with `names`.

If you want to obtain both the row and column names of the data frame, see `dimnames`.